# Temporary tables in Packages - Oracle

Tags: performance, oracle, package

I am kind of new in Oracle.
I am trying to create a package that has several functions.
This is the pseudocode of what I want to do

```
function FunctionA(UserID, startdate, enddate)
  /* Select TransactionDate, Amount
     from TableA
     where TransactionDate between startdate and enddate
     and TableA.UserID = UserID */
  Return TransactionDate, Amount
end FunctionA

function FunctionB(UserID, startdate, enddate)
  /* Select TransactionDate, Amount
     from TableB
     where TransactionDate between startdate and enddate
     and TableB.UserID = UserID */
  Return TransactionDate, Amount
end FunctionA

TYPE TRANSACTION_REC IS RECORD(
          TransactionDate    DATE,
          TransactionAmt     NUMBER);

function MainFunction(startdate, enddate)
  return TBL
  is
  vTrans TRANSACTION_REC;
begin
  FOR rec IN
    ( Select UserID, UserName, UserStatus
      from UserTable
      where EntryDate between startdate and enddate )
  LOOP
    vTrans := FunctionA(rec.UserID, startdate, enddate)

    if vTrans.TransactionDate is null then
       vTrans := FunctionB(rec.UserID, startdate, enddate)

       if vTrans.TransactionDate is null then
           rec.UserStatus := 'Inactive'
       endif;
    endif;
  END Loop;

  PIPE ROW(USER_OBJ_TYPE(rec.UserID,
                       rec.UserName,
                       rec.UserStatus,
                       vTrans.TransactionDate,
                       vTtans.TransactionAmt));
end MainFunction
```

Running this kind of code takes a long time because TableA and TableB is a very large table, and I am only getting 1 entry per record from the tables.

I would want to create a temporary table (TempTableA, TempTableB) within the package that will temporarily store all records based on the startdate and enddate, so that when I try to retrieve the TransactionDate and Amount for each rec, I will only refer to the TempTables (which is smaller than TableA and TableB).

I also want to take into consideration if the UserID is not found in TableA and TableB. So basically, when there are no records found in TableA and TableB, I also want the entry in the output, but it is indicated that the user is inactive.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Why don't you optimize the SQL used for each table? If you are only getting a single row in each select that kind of implies your userid is unique. Do you have a (unique) index on that column? If not you should add one (or even a primary key). Retrieving a single row based on a unique index will be very fast (and nearly independent of the size of the table)

Comment: Your additional pseudo-code is frankly rubbish. It's a hodge-podge of things which won't compile.  If you want somebody to write the code for you, you should post your actual full requirements instead of asking people to guess them from some shonky PL/SQL.  Of course, it is not the role of respondents on SO to do your job for you, but perhaps somebody will be feeling extra generous.

Answer (score 3):

SQL is a set-based language.  It is far more efficient to execute one statement which returns all the rows you need than to execute many statements which each return a single row.

Here is one way of getting all your rows at once.  It uses a common table expression because you read the whole of the UserTable and you should only do that once.

```
with cte as 
  (select UserID
         , UserStatus
   from UserTable )
select cte.UserID
       , cte.UserStatus
       , TableA.TransactionDate 
       , TableA.Amount  
from cte join TableA   
     on (cte.UserID = TableA.UserID)
where cte.UserStatus = 'A'
and TableA.TransactionDate between startdate and enddate
union
select cte.UserID
       , cte.UserStatus
       , TableB.TransactionDate 
       , TableB.Amount  
from cte join TableB  
     on (cte.UserID = TableB.UserID)
where cte.UserStatus != 'A'
and TableB.TransactionDate between startdate and enddate
```

---

By the way, be careful with temporary tables.  They aren't like temporary tables in T-SQL.  They are permanent heap tables, it's just their data that's temporary.  This means that populating a temporary table is an expensive process, because the database writes all those rows to disk.  Consequently we need to be certain that the performance gain we get by reading a dataset from a temporary table is worth the overhead of all those writes.

That certainly would not be the case with your code.  In fact, it is really pretty rare that the answer to a performance question turns out to be  "Use a Global Temporary Table", at least not in Oracle.  Better queries are the way to go, and in particular, embracing the Joy of Sets!

Comment: Thank you @APC. I appreciate your help :)
I have anther case to consider though.
I forgot to take into consideration cases when there is no record found in TableA and TableB (please see my updated pseudocode in my question)
sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Probably better to do it in one query, e.g.:

```
Select UserTable.UserID, UserTable.UserName, UserTable.UserStatus
      ,TableA.TransactionDate AS ATransactionDate
      ,TableA.Amount          AS AAmount
      ,TableB.TransactionDate AS BTransactionDate
      ,TableB.Amount          AS BAmount
from UserTable
left join TableA
  on (UserTable.UserID = TableA.UserID)
left join TableB
  on (UserTable.UserID = TableB.UserID)
where UserTable.EntryDate between startdate and enddate
```